# Taking a URL(String) and just getting the value need from it

Tags: c#, substring

I am currently working on an application that will create a new folder for any user who decides to join a group.  I am currently receiving a URL and would need to out certain parts in order to keep the user's name.  This URL will always be the same for all users in our company, the only thing that changes will be the user name that proceeds "personal/".  The name changes with different user, all I need will be the first and Last name.

```
For example    

string url = "https://dhgdev-my.sharepoint.com/personal/john_dough_dhgdev_com";

string name = \\ looking to cut off john_dough only* and leave out "_com" 

oneDrive.CreateNewOneDriveFolder("testthis"+ name); \\ creating a new folder and concatenating the name revived from URL
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and ask a question

Comment: Can you more clearly define the part of the string you wish to retrieve?  What if they have a double barreled surname etc?

Comment: U want to retrieve only 2 word in last segment ?

Comment: What is the distinction between the name and the remainder of the string. It is easy to find the last part of the Uri, but differentiate between the name and the rest is impossible. Do you have alsways this string ending in _dhgdev_com_ ?

Comment: And the username could be not in the last segment? Could you explain your url structure?

Comment: URL will be the same "dhgdev-my.sharepoint.com/personal".  the only thing to that I will need will be the name that proceeds personal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are "https://dhgdev-my.sharepoint.com/personal" and "_dhgdev_com" fixed? If yes, you can remove the fixed parts as follows:

```
var url = "https://dhgdev-my.sharepoint.com/personal/john_dough_dhgdev_com";
var name = url.Replace("https://dhgdev-my.sharepoint.com/personal/", string.Empty).Replace("_dhgdev_com", string.Empty);
```

**Note**: this an example (I'm not a fan of using nested method calls).

Comment: If you downvote, at least explain why. The OP Question isn't perfectly clear and I gave him an answer with a certain assumption / question.

Answer (score 2):

Well if always is the last part of your URL, you can do this:

```
string name= url.Split('/').Last();
```

Also, if you need an specific segment, you can also do this:

```
var name=new Uri(url).Segments.Last();
```

### Update:

In case you don't know in which segment could be the username, you can try with this solution;

```
int index = url.LastIndexOf("/personal/");
string rhs = url.Substring(index + 10);
var userNameSegment=rhs.Split('_');
var userName = userNameSegment[0] +"_"+userNameSegment[1];
```

If always the url have the same structure and the username is in the last segment then use one of the two solutions that I proposed above to get the last segment and apply the same operations to get the username.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Uri from that string and read the desidered value from Segments

```
string url = "https://dhgdev-my.sharepoint.com/personal/john_dough_dhgdev_com";
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
Console.WriteLine(uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length-1]);
```

**EDIT**
Looking at your revised question it seems that you want to remove also the last two substrings in the final segment. It this is the case, after obtaining the last segment of the Uri, you could proceed with simple string manipulations

```
string name = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length-1];
string[] parts = name.Split('_');
// a bit of checks on the parts length is required here
if(parts.Length > 2)
    name = string.Join("_", parts.Take(parts.Length  - 2));
```

Of course, if you need to remove just the `_com` part then you should adjust the constant 2 used above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to get the name:

```
string pattern = @"^.*\/(!?.*\/)(.*)$";
string input = "https://dhgdev-my.sharepoint.com/personal/john_dough_dhgdev_com";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
```

Then extract the name from a group in the expression:

```
match.Groups[1]; //Equal to "john_dough_dhgdev_com"
```

However, if you are looking to match only URLs that contain "personal" before the username if listed, you may want to use `^.*\/(!?.*\/)personal\/(.*)$` as the Regex pattern instead.

(I am away from my computer with Visual Studio, so I cannot test this)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way other than regex is likely to be:

```
        var url = "https://dhgdev-my.sharepoint.com/personal/john_dough_dhgdev_com";
        var extractname = url.Replace("https://dhgdev-my.sharepoint.com/personal/", string.Empty).Replace("_dhgdev_com", string.Empty);
```

Edit seen @Starceaker was first with the same solution.

Comment: Mine was downvoted so perhaps it's not a good answer, not sure why though. Thanks for the edit.